# How can I add this conditional constraint to my model in Python?

Tags: optimization, python, gurobi

I am creating an optimization model with 2 sets of binary decision variables. The first, `site`, is regarding which of 380 cities to place manufacturing sites in, and the second, `ASSG` is regarding which of 12 cities each manufacturing site will be assigned to service.  There will be 3 manufacturing sites total.

I need to add a constraint that the sum of all cities serviced by a *potential* manufacturing site is the number of cities that need serviced, `12`, but this limit needs to be `0` if a manufacturing site is not placed in that location.

This is difficult for me to explain so I've included a screenshot of the Excel model I am trying to scale-up using Python.  The "Logical constraint" is what I am trying to code into Python:

[image]

I know this code is a bit of a mess, I'm not great with dictionaries and there's too much going on here for me to keep track of it, but this is what I have so far:

```py
site = m.addVars(siteLoc, vtype=GRB.BINARY, name='site')  # siteLoc is a list of 380 potential mfg site locations
ASSG = m.addVars(siteASSG, vtype=GRB.BINARY, name='ASSG') # siteASSG is a gurobi tuplelist of the format: (potential mfg site location, one of 12 cities mfg site will service)
m.update()

m.addConstr(sum(val for key, val in ASSG.items() if key[0] == k for k in site.keys()) <= 12 * val for key, val in site.items())
```

Comment: I noticed that in the code you shared, you have `if key[0] ==k` but you use `k` in the second for loop. If this is your problem, you may want to change that order in your `sum` i.e. `sum(val for key, val in ASSG.items() for k in site.keys() if key[0] == k) <= ...`

Comment: @EhsanK Thank you. That does make more sense, what would you suggest I do with the right hand side? That side should be either `0` or `12` depending on that item's value in `site`.

Comment: @EhsanK I have tried `<= 12 * k for k in site.keys()` on the right-hand side but that gives me `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'generator' and 'NoneType'`

Comment: @JacobMyer are you using Gurobi interface for modeling your problem? I am not familiar with that but I think you need to mention the type of variables (integer, real, binary...) when you define the variables.

Comment: @OguzToragay I usually do but it was left out of an example that I was following. I've added `vtype=GRB.BINARY` to be sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understood the problem correctly, you can have $380$ binary variables  $x_{i}$ that can be defined as follows:

$$x_{i}=\begin{cases}
1, & \text{If location}\,\,i \,\,\text{has been selected for a manufacturing site}\\
0, & \text{Otherwise} \\
\end{cases}$$

and for the chosen sites:

$$y_{ij}=\begin{cases}
1, & \text{If site}\, \, i \, \, \text{serves city} \, j\\
0, & \text{Otherwise} \\
\end{cases}$$

then you need to add the following constraints to your model:

\begin{cases}\sum\limits_i x_{i}=3 \ \ \forall i \in \{1,2,\dots,380\}\\\sum\limits_j y_{ij} \le 12 \ \ \forall i \in \{\text{chosen sites}\}\\\sum\limits_i y_{ij}=1 \ \ \forall i \in \{\text{chosen sites}\}\,\,\text{and} \ \ \forall j \in \{1,2,\cdots,12\}\end{cases}

first and second constraints can be combined to force the model to assign the $12$ cities to those $3$ cities (out of $380$ potentials) that have a manufacturing site placed in. The constraint would be as follow:

$$\sum_j y_{ij} \le 12 \times x_i  \ \ \forall i$$

Now, to define the aforementioned constraint in Python (the code is based on Pyomo but I believe it is almost the same if you use solver interfaces as well):

```py
import numpy as np
from pyomo.environ import *
model.sites = set(np.arange(1,381)) #Index for the potential locations
model.cities  = set(np.arange(1,13)) #Index for the 12 cities with demands
cons = pyomo.constraint((sum y[i,j] for j in model.cities) <= 12*x[i] for i in model.sites)
```

Comment: I probably should have been more clear about what `ASSG` and `site` were.  I've edited my post to clarify that.  These are my decision variables, would you suggest I modify the decision variables I am using perhaps?

Comment: Even after modifying my decision variables so that `ASSG` is just the names of the 12 cities with demands, I am receiving the same `unsupported operand type(s)...` error.  What could be causing this? @Oguz

Comment: @JacobMyer have a look at this similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46476277

Comment: Thanks for your help! I've gotten all of the error messages sorted out.  I'm not used to reading mathematical notation like you have written here so I am trying to make sense of the constraints you have listed and I think that I still need another?  My code so far looks like: 
line 1: `m.addConstr(sum(Loc.values()) <= 3) # max number of manufacturing sites`
line 2:`m.addConstrs((quicksum(ASSG[i,j[1]] for j in siteASSG) <= 12 * site[i] for i in siteLoc), 'site-city-relation')`
line 3: `m.update() `

Comment: Do my constraints look correct to you? I still need one to assure that all of the 12 cities with demand are associated with a mfg site and I'm not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 3):

My answer was longer than I could put it in a comment:

I don't know how you defined your variables `site` and `ASSG`, so here is what I think should be your constraint (I based it on @Oguz formulation):

```
from gurobipy import * # I assume this is how you imported

SITES = range(380)  # index i
CITIES = range(12)  # index j
m.addConstrs((quicksum(ASSG[i,j] for j in CITIES) <= 12 * site[i] for i in SITES), 'site-city-relation')
```

Note that I'm using `addConstrs` (plural)

Comment: One difference between my code and your solution here that I think is important is that `site` and `ASSG` are my model's decision variables. I will update my post to show how they were created.  I think this might have something to do with why I am receiving: `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'generator' and 'NoneType'` @EhsanK

Comment: @JacobMyer Based on your update, both `site` and `ASSG` are `tupledict` which means `tuplelist` as keys and gurobi `Var` as values. But you can still access them as I put above. You just need to change `SITES` to `siteLoc` and `CITIES` to `siteASSG` in the constraint (again note that it's `addConstrs` (plural)). Your error is likely to go away

Comment: Okay I still have to create the objective function and make sure that I have all of the necessary constraints (see my comment under Oguz's response), but this has gotten rid of the error messages :D  @EhsanK