# Having trouble with objective function in Python: "GurobiError: Variable not in model". What else could I try?

Tags: optimization, python, gurobi

I am trying to figure out how I can write this objective function into python using Gurobi.  I have to minimize the sum of the product of three dictionary's values.  The reason I am confused is that while the first two dictionaries I am multiplying are the same length (somewhere in the thousands), the third has only 12 items. Also the first two dictionaries have tuple keys and the third does not.

The first dictionary `ASSG` is a decision variable that has the format:

```py
ASSG = {('Abilene, TX', 'Boston, MA'): <gurobi.Var ASSG[Abilene, TX,Boston, MA]>, 
        ('Abilene, TX', 'Chicago, IL'): <gurobi.Var ASSG[Abilene, TX,Chicago, IL]>,
        ('Abilene, TX', 'Dallas, TX'): <gurobi.Var ASSG[Abilene, TX,Dallas, TX]>,
        ('Abilene, TX', 'Denver, CO'): <gurobi.Var ASSG[Abilene, TX,Denver, CO]>,
        ...}
```

The second dictionary is `miles` and it has the following format:

```py
miles = {('Abilene, TX', 'Boston, MA'): 2091.92,
         ('Abilene, TX', 'Chicago, IL'): 1148.37,
         ('Abilene, TX', 'Dallas, TX'): 189.87,
         ('Abilene, TX', 'Denver, CO'): 775.6,
        ...}
```

The third dictionary is called `Demand` and it looks like:

```py
Demand = {'Boston, MA': 1051,
          'Chicago, IL': 940,
          'Dallas, TX': 1131,
          'Denver, CO': 466,
          'Los Angeles, CA': 1301,
          'Richmond, VA': 1171,
          'Miami, FL': 1463,
          'New York, NY': 1120,
          'Phoenix, AZ': 665,
          'Pittsburgh, PA': 1280,
          'San Fransisco, CA': 615,
          'Seattle, WA': 528}
```

I think what I need to do is multiply all of the values where the keys in `Demand` match the second element in the tuple of `ASSG` and `miles`'s keys.  i.e. All the items with `'Boston, MA'` get multiplied, all the Chicagos, all the Dallases...

I have tried multiplying them separately and then using quicksum but I receive an error:

```py
a = {k: ASSG[k]*miles[k] for k in ASSG}
b = {k:Demand.get(k[1], 1)* v for k,v in x.items()}

m.setObjective(quicksum(b.values()))
m.ModelSense = GRB.MINIMIZE
m.update()

GurobiError: Variable not in model
```

Comment: If there is any other portion of this model that you think I need to share please let me know!

Comment: 1) What is `x` that you used in definining `b`? Is it `ASSG` variable? 2) If what you want is something like $\sum\limits_{ij}\text{demand}_i\times \text{miles}_{ij}\times \text{ASSG}_{ij}$ then just loop over `i` and `j`. something like: `quicksum(Demand[i]*miles[i,j]*val for (i,j), val in ASSG.items())`

Comment: @EhsanK thankyou. That is the equation that I am looking for, but that code returns `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)`

Comment: check my edit. I forgot to put `items()` after `ASSG`. Without that, you're just looping over the keys and that's why it told you expected only 2.

Comment: that was one of the first things I tried and it returned `KeyError: 'Abilene, TX'` , I fixed this by changing `Demand[i]` to `Demand[j]`.  This allowed the model to run but there is another issue: no solution was found. I am assuming this has to do with the constraints we discussed here (https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/2837/how-can-i-add-this-conditional-constraint-to-my-model-in-python/2838?noredirect=1#comment3012_2838) as this is the same model  @EhsanK

Comment: Since you've solved your model in Excel successfully (it seems), why don't you write-up the mathematical formulation (similar to what Oguz showed you in the other question) and then also write the `.lp` file from gurobi in the above model where you get no results (you can do that with `m.write('my_model.lp')`). That shows you the differences between what you wrote and what you actually have in python and the modifications you need to make.